# storing a value in a variable in conjunction with if

Tags: javascript, mediawiki

I'm trying to create a talk page link that changes based on what namespace you might be in. For instance if you're in mainspace you'll be directed to Talk: if in category to Category_talk:. I have this so far:

```
var namespace = if (wgNamespaceNumber == '0') {
    return ('Talk');
} else {
    return (mw.config.get( 'wgCanonicalNamespace' ) + '_talk');
}
```

But it's just returning a syntax error, unexpected token if. I'm guessing you can't use if in this way?

Answer (score 2):

[`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) is for passing a value or object out of a function, not blocks like `if/else`.

```
var namespace;

if (wgNamespaceNumber == '0') {
    namespace = 'Talk';
} else {
    namespace = mw.config.get( 'wgCanonicalNamespace' ) + '_talk';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You guessed right. You can't assign an IF like that.

Change your code into

```
var namespace = null;

if (wgNamespaceNumber == '0') {
    namespace = 'Talk';
} else {
    namespace =  (mw.config.get( 'wgCanonicalNamespace' ) + '_talk');
}
```

And it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return anything. You can just set the value of the variable based on the condition. The function will however need to return a value.

```
var namespace = (wgNamespaceNumber == '0')
    ? 'Talk'
    : mw.config.get( 'wgCanonicalNamespace' );
```

The condition above is called a ternary ([**MDN explains it better**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator))